# Filter from two array of objects and then merge them

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

My requirement is to find common objects from two arrays and based on either `Phone` or `Email` i.e if Phone is `null or ''` then find common using Email and vice versa. After finding the common from two arrays, I want to merge these two objects so that they both have the same key/value pairs. I've managed to find the common but failed to merge them. This is what I've done so far.

**Array1:**

```
[
  {
    "Name": "Name1",
    "Phone": "",
    "Email": "name1@mail.com",
    "ID": 1
  },
  {
    "Name": "Name2",
    "Phone": "12345566",
    "Email": "name2@mail.com",
    "ID": 2
  }
]
```

**Array2:**

```
[
  {
    "Name": "Name1",
    "Phone": "987654321",
    "Email": "name1@mail.com"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Name2",
    "Phone": "12345566",
    "Email": "name2@mail.com"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Name3",
    "Phone": "23445677",
    "Email": ""
  }
]
```

This is how I managed to get the common from these two.

```
const common = array1
                  .filter(user=> 
                  array2.some(otherUser => 
                  (user.Email && (user.Email === otherUser.Email)) ||
                  (user.Phone && (user.Phone === otherUser.Phone))));
```

How would i merge these two without using the loop on `common` array because that would take alot of time as my data in array could contain records in thousands?
What is the best way to achieve this using `ES6`?

Comment: But your `filter` function already doing loop in his core. Why don't you replace `filter` with cycle, which will do filter and add data to `array1`?

Comment: Is there a chance, records having same e-mail/phone have different names? Expected resulting array would be fine for complete problem statement.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov yes, records can have different Names as well

Comment: @Grabatui I was thinking of doing this using `ES6`. Is there a way using that?

Comment: Your test on Email and Phone is not correct, what are you expecting this to do?  I would replace the test with (typeof user.Email == "string" && user.Email.length > 0) then add your string comparison part after this.

Comment: Where is the data coming from? If it's from a database connection, it may make sense to optimize the query instead of filtering / merging via code as you won't get rid of the looping for the commons.

Comment: For ten thousand records and repeated searches, you need to rearrange your data.  Consider creating an indexed version of the data grouped by phone or e-mail and it will make these types of operations quick and straightforward.

Comment: @k0pernikus Thank for the suggestion. I would definitely improve the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is clear. Just override the value of filtered array when you compare the values using `some()`.

**Example:**

```js
const arr1 = [{ "Name": "Name1", "Phone": "", "Email": "name1@mail.com", "ID": 1 },{ "Name": "Name2", "Phone": "12345566", "Email": "name2@mail.com", "ID": 2 }];
const arr2 = [{"Name": "Name1","Phone": "987654321","Email": "name1@mail.com"},{"Name": "Name2","Phone": "12345566","Email": "name2@mail.com"},{"Name": "Name3","Phone": "23445677","Email": ""}];

const arr3 = arr1.filter(i => {
    return arr2.some(v => {
        if (i.Phone === v.Phone || i.Email === v.Email) {
            !i.Phone && (i.Phone = v.Phone), !i.Email && (i.Phone = v.Email)
            return !0
        }
    })
})

console.log(arr3)
```

Comment: But what about "Name3"? It looks like this user has been dropped in your merge process.

Answer (score 0):

**Using `for loop`**

```js
const arra1 = [
  {
    Name: 'Name1',
    Phone: '',
    Email: 'name1@mail.com',
    ID: 1,
  },
  {
    Name: 'Name2',
    Phone: '12345566',
    Email: 'name2@mail.com',
    ID: 2,
  },
];


const arr2 = [
  {
    Name: 'Name1',
    Phone: '987654321',
    Email: 'name1@mail.com',
  },
  {
    Name: 'Name2',
    Phone: '12345566',
    Email: 'name2@mail.com',
  },
  {
    Name: 'Name3',
    Phone: '23445677',
    Email: '',
  },
];

const common = [];

for (let i = 0; i < arra1.length; i += 1) {
  const element = arra1[i];
  const { Phone, Email } = element;
  let searchKey = null;
  let searchValue = null;
  if (Phone) {
    searchKey = 'Phone';
    searchValue = Phone;
  } else if (Email) {
    searchKey = 'Email';
    searchValue = Email;
  }
  const index = arr2.findIndex((r) => {
    return searchKey ? r[searchKey] === searchValue : false;
  });
  if (index > -1) {
    common.push(element);
  }
}

console.log(common);
```

**Using `filter`**

```js
const arra1 = [
  {
    Name: 'Name1',
    Phone: '',
    Email: 'name1@mail.com',
    ID: 1,
  },
  {
    Name: 'Name2',
    Phone: '12345566',
    Email: 'name2@mail.com',
    ID: 2,
  },
];


const arr2 = [
  {
    Name: 'Name1',
    Phone: '987654321',
    Email: 'name1@mail.com',
  },
  {
    Name: 'Name2',
    Phone: '12345566',
    Email: 'name2@mail.com',
  },
  {
    Name: 'Name3',
    Phone: '23445677',
    Email: '',
  },
];

const common = arra1.filter((f) => {
  const { Phone, Email } = f;
  let searchKey = null;
  let searchValue = null;
  if (Phone) {
    searchKey = 'Phone';
    searchValue = Phone;
  } else if (Email) {
    searchKey = 'Email';
    searchValue = Email;
  }
  const index = arr2.findIndex((r) => {
    return searchKey ? r[searchKey] === searchValue : false;
  });
  return !!(index > -1);
});

console.log(common);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using map and find. However, this only find missing fields from array 1 into array 2. If you need a full join, you would have to do it twice and then use an Object.assign().

```
const common = array1.map(user => {
    if ((user.Email && user.Phone) || (!user.Email && !user.Phone)) {
        return user;
    }
    else if (!user.Phone) {
        const match = array2.find(otherUser => {
            return otherUser.Email === user.Email;
        });
        user.Phone = match.Phone;
    }
    else if (!user.Email) {
        const match = array2.find(otherUser => {
            return otherUser.Phone === user.Phone;
        });
        user.Email = match.Email;
    }
    return user;
})
```

First "if" is useful to avoid iterating second array if both fields are filled or missing.

Answer (score 0):

This is a two phase approach that works with any number of arrays to be merged.

First all entries are put together in one object (`merged`), having a combination of Email and Phone-no. as the key. Then I consolidate it further by combining entries with partial keys with those having a full key identification.

```js
var arr1= [
  { "Name": "Name1", "Phone": "", "Email": "name1@mail.com", "ID": 1 },
  { "Name": "Name2", "Phone": "12345566", "Email": "name2@mail.com", "ID": 2 },
  { "Name": "Name3", "Phone": "23445677", "Email": "name3@mail.com" } ],
     arr2=[
  { "Name": "Name1", "Phone": "987654321", "Email": "name1@mail.com" },
  { "Name": "Name2", "Phone": "12345566", "Email": "name2@mail.com" },
  { "Name": "Name3", "Phone": "23445677", "Email": "" , "ID": 3 }
];

console.log(merge(arr1,arr2))

function merge(arr) {
  var merged={};
  for (var i=1;i<arguments.length;i++) arr=arr.concat(arguments[i]);
  arr.forEach(function(o){ // first round of merging ...
    var k=(o.Email||'')+'|'+(o.Phone||'');
    if (!merged[k]) merged[k]=o;
    else for (p in o) merged[k][p]=o[p];
  });
  var keys=Object.keys(merged);
  keys.forEach((k,i)=>{
    var l=k.length,p,o=merged[k];
    // now look for partial matches (only phone no. given)
    if (k[0]=='|'){ keys.forEach((kk,j)=>{
      if(j!=i && kk.substr(kk.length-l)==k) {
        for (p in o) if(o[p]) merged[kk][p]=o[p];
        delete merged[k];
      }
      })
    }
    else if (k[l-1]=='|'){ keys.forEach((kk,j)=>{
    // partial matches (only email given)
      if(j!=i && kk.substr(0,l)==k) {
        for (p in o) if(o[p]) merged[kk][p]=o[p];
        delete merged[k];
      }
      })
    }
  })
  return Object.values(merged)
}
```